# Docker networking: how to show connected containers names

Tags: docker

I'm building a Docker (1.9.1) network and attaching a few containers to it.
`docker network inspect NETWORK` lists the connected containers, but refers to them only with the containers IDs, while I'd like to see also their names.

I haven't found an option for the `docker network inspect` command to achieve this. Is parsing externally, e.g. with a script, the output of this command together with the output of `docker ps` the only current way?

**EDIT** This is what I've written in python (2.7) as an helper to identify the IP address associated to containers inside a docker network (passing the network name as argument):

```
import json
import subprocess
import sys

network_name = sys.argv[1]
network_json = subprocess.check_output(["docker", "network", "inspect", network_name])
network = json.loads(network_json)
containers = network[0]['Containers']

for container_id in containers:
    container_name = subprocess.check_output(["docker", "inspect", "--format", "'{{ .Name }}'", container_id])
    print container_id + " " + container_name.strip() + ": " + containers[container_id]['IPv4Address']
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this script:

```
 if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    nw=($(docker network ls | awk 'NR>=2 {printf "%s ",$2}'))
else
    nw=$@
fi

echo ${nw[@]}
for network in ${nw[@]};do

    docker network ls | grep $network 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo -e "\nNetwork $network not found!"
        exit 1
    fi

    ids=$(docker network inspect $network | grep -E "^\s+\".{64}\"" | awk -F\" '{printf "%s ",substr($2,0,12)}')
    echo -e "\nContainers in network $network:"
    for id in ${ids[@]}; do
        name=$(docker ps -a | grep $id | awk '{print $NF}')
        echo -e "\t$id: $name"
    done
    shift
done
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, so this confirms there isn't any hidden option or format option in `docker network inspect`... A colleague suggested a Pull Request should be created on docker to include it, which is probably the right thing to do.